# Ansible AWS VPC Network Registering

Tags: ansible

I have the following situation

```
--- 
- name: Create VPC 
  hosts: localhost
  tasks: 
  - name: create a VPC with default tenancy and a couple of tags
    amazon.aws.ec2_vpc_net:
      name: Ansible
      cidr_block: 10.0.0.0/16
      region: us-east-1
      state: present
      tags:
        Name: Ansible
        Team: DevOps
      tenancy: default
```

I am planning to use the VPC id in below subnet

```
- name: Create subnet for database servers
  amazon.aws.ec2_vpc_subnet:
    state: present
    vpc_id: vpc-123456
    cidr: 10.0.1.16/28
    tags:
      Name: Database Subnet
  register: database_subnet
```

But, I dont want to copy and paste the VPC ID, instead I want ansible dynamically pull VPC ID from above code. I did some research, and I found there is a way of registering it. However, all the documentations are outdated after ansible 2.4
Can someone please share how to interpolate VPD id in subnet?

Thanks

Comment: In your VPC creation task, add a [`register: vpc`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables). Then [`debug`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html#parameter-var) it to see what it contains.

Comment: Else: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_vpc_net_module.html#return-values